# Data binding: Why RecyclerView.Adapter onClick event is not fire?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.0, Java 8.

```
dataBinding { enabled = true }
```

Here my RecyclerView adapter code (java file):

```
    public class OfferSortAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Offer, OfferSortAdapter.OfferViewHolder> {     

        @Override
        public OfferSortAdapter.OfferViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            OfferItemBinding offerItemBinding = OfferItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
            return new OfferViewHolder(offerItemBinding.getRoot(), offerItemBinding);
   }      
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(OfferSortAdapter.OfferViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            Offer offer = getItem(position);
            holder.offerItemBinding.setOffer(offer);
        }
        public static class OfferViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            @BindView(R.id.imageViewPhoto)
            ImageView imageViewPhoto;    
            OfferItemBinding offerItemBinding; 

            private OfferViewHolder(View view, OfferItemBinding offerItemBinding) {
                super(view);
                this.offerItemBinding = offerItemBinding;
                ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            }

            public void onClickImageViewPhoto(View view) {
                  // not call this method
            }
        }
    }
```

Here xml layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">    
    <data>    
      <variable name="handlers"               type="myproject.OfferSortAdapter.OfferViewHolder" />
    </data>    
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickImageViewPhoto}"/>
</layout>
```

As you can see I set onClickHandler on xml layout: `@{handlers::onClickImageViewPhoto}`

But the method `onClickImageViewPhoto` not call when I click on ImageView.

Comment: It would be good to state the straight-forward question in your post.

Comment: I found solution. I must call `setHanlders()`. Somethinkg like this: `OfferViewHolder offerViewHoder = new OfferViewHolder(offerItemBinding.getRoot(), offerItemBinding);
        offerItemBinding.setHandlers(offerViewHoder);`

Comment: Can you please update the above code. So that i can get clear idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set Handler object in your binding class.

```
OfferItemBinding offerItemBinding = OfferItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
OfferViewHolder offerViewHoder = new OfferViewHolder(offerItemBinding.getRoot(), offerItemBinding); 
offerItemBinding.setHandlers(offerViewHoder);
return offerViewHoder;
```

**Suggestion.**

There is no need to use `ButterKnife` as you can access your layout component like

```
binidng.image_view_photo
```

Just remember these fields are generated in snake case. `imageViewPhoto` will be converted to `image_view_photo`.